# Helm configMap support for binary files

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap

I am trying to create a helm chart of kind ConfigMap that will replace the following command from kubernates.

```
kubectl create configmap my-config -n $namespace --from-file=./my-directory
```

`my-directory` contains around 5 files, 2 of them are properties file and 2 of them jpg file. I see the following result for `kubectl get cm`, I can see `4` DATA files in configMap

```
[admin@cluster ~]$ kubectl get cm
NAME                   DATA   AGE
warm-up-config         4      41m
```

I created a template as follows, it work if I specify only properties file but If I add jpg files it doesn't work at all

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-config
data:
{{ (.Files.Glob "resources/*").AsConfig | nindent 2 }}
```

Does anyone know how I make this work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JPG files are binary, and should be added as such.

```
data:
  binaryData:
    {{ .Files.Get "/path/to/file.jpg" }}
```

Files in `binaryData` field must be encoded with base64, so:

```
{{ .Files.Get "/path/to/file.jpg" | b64enc }}
```

Don't forget proper indentation:

```
{{ .Files.Get "/path/to/file.jpg" | b64enc | nindent 4 }}
```

Comment: Important: as defined here https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/ .Files don't load file from anywhere. So "/path/to/file.jpg" if /path/to is not part of your chart folder